# R studio stopped working. Uninstall and re install but packages all cant be detected

Tags: r

I tried running a pacman package and found it could not be installed. I tried installing tidyverse package individually and it says error. Now R is not able to run since all packages cannot be installed.

Lastly, uninstalled R studio and re install but it is still facing an issue.

````
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to access index for repository https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib:
  cannot open URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/PACKAGES'
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/Syed Ismail/Documents/R/win-library/4.0’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to access index for repository https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib:
  cannot open URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/PACKAGES'
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘pacman’ is not available for this version of R

A version of this package for your version of R might be available elsewhere,
see the ideas at
https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-patched/R-admin.html#Installing-packages
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to access index for repository https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.0:
  cannot open URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.0/PACKAGES'```
````

Comment: (1/n) That *warning* says that your R cannot see the CRAN repo at RStudio. Nothing will work if it cannot see the repo. This might be your internet is dead, or you caught rstudio.com in a network glitch. Try again. If it fails consistently, then look into your firewall, anti-virus, and/or anti-malware to see what might be blocking the network connections (since I'm inferring you asking here on SO indicates the internet as a whole is fine for you).

Comment: (2/n) If you cannot start RStudio, then you should still be able to start R by itself and start the package reinstall. You can start "R" by itself either with the windows start menu or, if that fails too (you need to give us the errors it says), then open `cmd.exe`, navigate to the R directory (perhaps `c:/R/R-4.0.4/bin/x64` and run `R --vanilla --no-site`. From there, install the broken packages that prevent RStudio from running.

Comment: (3/3) Lastly, check for `.Rprofile` or `.Rdata` files that might be interrupting R starting (likely the latter). Move them out of the way temporarily, fix your packages, then you can move them back if needed. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks mate. It works now. Apparently school internet was blocking the packages from being download which is weird.